# Sub fields of $\mathbb{C}$ that are splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hi I really need help in how to determine sub fields $L$ of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and finding $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$.  The question is:

Find subfields $L$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that are splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$, find $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\mathrm{(i)} & t^8 + 1 \\
\mathrm{(ii)} & t^4  -4t^2  +1\\
\mathrm{(iii)} & t^3  -5\\
\mathrm{(iv)}  & t^{17}  - 1\\
\end{array}$$

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

For example take $t^3 - 5$ the roots of this polynomial are: $\sqrt{5}, \xi \sqrt{5}, \xi^2 \sqrt{5}$. Here $\xi$ is the primitive root of unity of order $3$. Now you note that you need to add both $\sqrt{5}$ and $\xi$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, for the polynomial to split. Hence $L = \mathbb{Q}(\xi,\sqrt{5})$. Now if you take $F = \mathbb{Q}(\xi)$, then $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = [L:F][F:\mathbb{Q}]$. The extension $L/F$ is Kummer and $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclotomic, hence $[L:F] = 2$ and $[F:\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

The rest are very similar and most rely on cyclotomic extensions. Remember that if you add a primitive root of unity of order $n$, you'll get a field extension of degree $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.